# How to Instantiate a global or public object from within a method? C#

Tags: c#, new-operator, instantiation

I've been researching this for over a week now and I'm stumped.

I'm working with multiple forms in windows. Each form resides in its own namespace.  In the following code I'm instantiating a new form of the class Robo_Pass.  It resides in the Namespace Space_Pass. The form I'm working in is class Overseer and resides in the namespace Robo_Pi.

Please note that the use of multiple namespaces is not the problem. That much is working just fine.

In this program I being with:

using Space_Pass;  (I do this so I can access Robo_Pass without a need to specify the namespace it resides in.

Here's my code:

```
        public void Btn_Robo_Pass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Check to see if this Namespace/Form is open.
            bool test = check_App_Open("Robo_Pass"); 
            if (test == false) // if not, then create it. 
            {
                Robo_Pass pass = new  Robo_Pass();
                // set up event handler for when this form closes
                pass.FormClosed += Btn_Apps_Click;
                pass.TopMost=true;      
                pass.Show();        
                btn_Apps_.PerformClick();
            }
            else // If already open, then just call Window_Show(). 
            {
                Window_Show("Robo_Pass");
                btn_Apps_.PerformClick();               
            }   
        }
```

The only line in question is:

```
                Robo_Pass pass = new  Robo_Pass();
```

Is there anything I can add to this line to make this object named "pass" global to the rest of the program.

In other words, from other methods within this class I want to be able to call methods on the other form like so:

```
pass.method(variable);
```

I can actually do this if I create the object "pass" outside of a method. 
In other words if I move the following code to outside of any methods it works:

```
                Robo_Pass pass = new  Robo_Pass();
```

Then I can access the methods within it using

```
pass.method(variable);
```

But I need to create this object within the button click method shown originally.

So my question is this.

Is there any way I can create this object within that button method and have the object be available in other methods.

I tried adding keywords like static, public, global.  But my IDE rejects all of those in this context.

So I'm at a loss how to make this object named "pass" available to other methods in this class.

As I say, it works like a charm if I instantiate it outside of a method.  But can't do that.  I need to be able to instantiate it using a button.

Note: I apologize for any bad formatting or typos in this post.  I don't post here often but I'm really stumped on this one.   Hopefully it's an easy fix.  I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: It is not global if you declare it locally (inside a method).  Declaring an object variable and creating an instance are 2 different things

Comment: Does your "method" have a stable signature, or it varies from instance to instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the variable declaration outside your method and make it public, then instantiate it within your method:

```
public Robo_Pass pass = null;

public void Btn_Robo_Pass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ...
  pass = new  Robo_Pass();
  ... 
}
```

You can now access it through an instance of your class:

```
var yourClass = new YourClass();
yourClass.pass.method(variable);
```

If you want it to be availabe without even creating an object of your class, make it static:

```
public static Robo_Pass pass = null;
```

Then you can get it just by calling `YourClass.pass.method(variable)`. Just remember to make sure that it has been initialized first, or do a check to see if it's still null.